# NODE-RED IfluxDB How do i use a variable as indentifier of a query?

Tags: javascript, variables, influxdb, node-red

I;m having a problem declaring a query on influxdb, I can't declare the identifier as a variable

I'm using the following syntax:

```
msg.query = "SELECT time , Temper01, Temper02, Temper03, Temper04 FROM ID WHERE time >= '2021-11-11T14:00:00Z' AND time <= '2021-11-19T14:00:00Z' tz('America/Sao_Paulo') ";
```

Where `ID` is the variable, but it only works if I put directly the value of the variable .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not said where you are getting the value of `ID` from but assuming it's attached to a msg at `msg.payload.id`

You just build the string from parts:

```
msg.query = "SELECT time , Temper01, Temper02, Temper03, Temper04 FROM "
    + msg.payload.id
    + " WHERE time >= '2021-11-11T14:00:00Z' AND time <= '2021-11-19T14:00:00Z' tz('America/Sao_Paulo') ";
```