# How to get data from a especif Time period in InfluxDB Node-RED

Tags: javascript, timestamp, influxdb

I'm trying to read data from InfluxDB v1.x but only in a especific time period, Example:

Get the values of `temper01` from 2021-11-09/14:00:00  to 2021-11-10/14:00:00.

i know its possible with this code :

`"WHERE time >= '2021-11-09T14:00:00Z' AND time <= '2021-11-10T14:00:00Z'"`   But i wanna know if it is possible to use a variable instead of the direct timestamp.

i've tried this code :

```
msg.query = "SELECT time , Temper01, Temper02, Temper03 FROM "
+  global.get("ID_device1")
+ " WHERE time >= "
+   msg.payload;
+ " AND time <= '2021-11-18T00:00:00.000Z' " ;
```

but dosent matter the `msg.payload` value, it just get data from the very first data stored, and when i try to single quote `msg.payload` i get the  `invalid operation: time and *influxql.VarRef are not compatible"` error message.

Comment: Yes, in the same way as your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70066261/node-red-ifluxdb-how-do-i-use-a-variable-as-indentifier-of-a-query) question, the trick will be ensuring that the variable is in the right format.

Comment: im declaring directly a string with the timestamp for test, and  i build the string by parts now, but this time i'm getting this error :  ` Error: A 400 Bad Request error occurred: {"error":"error parsing query: invalid duration"} `

Comment: here is the declarition that i'm doing:  timestart = '2021-11-08T14:00:00Z';

Comment: Add some debug nodes and directly compare what works with what doesn't

Comment: i figured out the error, but i cant get the correct behavior, im doing the start date first, but  no matter with what a load the var it just start getting data from the very beggining, the msg.payload.startdate it is in the correct format, it just dosent seem to work propperly

Comment: Have you included the quotes?

Comment: quotes? what exactly do you mean?

Comment: As I said, use debug nodes to compare the output you know works with that which doesn't. Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70079910/edit) the question to show what you've actually tried.

Comment: i edited with i alreay tried, and the outputs in question are correct, the problem is that 
Apparently influxdb cant read the msg.payload correctly , atleast when it is comparing with  "time" or carrying a timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `msg.paylaod` looks something like `2020-11-18T00:00:00.000Z` then you have not quoted the time string you are inserting into the query.

It should look like this:

```
msg.query = "SELECT time , Temper01, Temper02, Temper03 FROM "
+  global.get("ID_device1")
+ " WHERE time >= '"
+   msg.payload;
+ "' AND time <= '2021-11-18T00:00:00.000Z' " ;
```

The difference is the `'` at the end of the string on the 3rd line and again at the start of the string on the last line.

Directly comparing a working version with the version that didn't work would have shown this.

Comment: It works man, im sorry im really a complete begginer with node-red and javascript, with you help i just find out that the node that im using gives this : "1635897600000" on the msg.payload. but in the debugger it converts to actuall time stamps, so i  thought that the output was right. im so dumb jees

Comment: Thanks a lot man, now i just have to find out how to convert this number to a timestamp so that the query can read. u helped me a lot man thanks.